# D7: Newsletter type project.The articles are grouped in a set (newsletter) published on a regular basis

Tags: views

My project is as follows:

News will be published like printed news letters meaning that no ongoing updating&publishing but clear intervals (in other words the articles need to be grouped together on the criteria of issue..issue January, issue February etc... At the moment plan is that publishing interval would be a few months.

What modules and approach would you choose for this? I know prosepoint can do this...but is no longer free and I need to make it in Drupal.

I need to dismiss the confusion with simplenews module. The newsletter doesn't need to be delivered by email (tough this would be one functionality) but displayed on the website.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution. There might be others but **node referencing** a good one.

Need to create 2 content types: one for issue and one for issue article. The issue article needs to have a reference field where to assign it to a specific issue. There are no date fields for articles but there are for issues.

I think the module **Reference** (former Node reference in D6) do that in Field UI. There you can assign a reference node field to the article content type to specify which issue it belongs.

Other module Node Reference URL Widget could be useful.

Also the articles need to be grouped as well using taxonomy. This helps also building the menu system.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO if your newsletter isn't meant to be emailed, the easier solution is using views with a filter on the date of nodes + a module that gives you the pdf display, like [Views_PDF](http://drupal.org/project/views_pdf).

Then if you want to send your issues by mail, you may extend with [Views pdf mime mail](http://drupal.org/project/views_pdf_mimemail) to attach the exact pdf to your mails, but it's still under development and I'm not sure if it works.
Please consider than whenever you talk about email newsletters, probably the most complete solution is still Simplenews and its submodules. If I were you, I would use [Simplenews Scheduler](http://drupal.org/project/simplenews_scheduler) + [Insert view](http://drupal.org/project/insert_view), like I did in a similar situation [D6].

Hope it helps